# Cleaning silt off magnets

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, ferromagnetism

I gone done a foolish thing; I got my set of spherical (⌀ 5 mm) neodymium magnets covered in of (what is presumably iron based) ferromagnetic silt/sand particles.

[image: chain of spherical magnets with black silt/sand at the joints, watch glass with larger particles in background]

With some difficulty, I've been able to remove most of the sand sized particles (by grabbing them with some needle-nose pliers).  But, the silt sized particles are much harder to remove — as the magnets are very strong, and the particles are very small.

**How can I effectively removed these small ferromagnetic particles from the magnets?**

Ideally I'd like to keep the silt, but my priority is to clean the magnets.
Obviously I don't want to permanently demagnetise the magnets.

Comment: You can try rolling them in an adhesive or dip them in wax and then break off the wax. Clay might work.

Comment: You might also consider caulking or rubber cement. Any matrix that can trap the particle and be peeled off after curing

Comment: My condolences. You could try putting them into a bucket with a sieve so the magnets can't get away but the sand can, and then blasting it with a pressure washer. I know from experience that shop air won't work. At least, not shop air at at around 150psi.

Comment: Try wiping them off with damp cloth.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that using an adhesive can work well to remove small pieces of dust like this. I have used packing tape to pull the particles off of small neodymium magnets.

I found this method on the K&J magnetics FAQ page, [link here](https://www.kjmagnetics.com/FAQ.asp).

Answer (score 0):

I have now tried using the suggestions provided (both in the comments and in the other answer), and wish to share my results:

- The adhesive **tape** (a cloth tape) that I used was effective at removing the silt.  But, I found that this is not a great method, because it is not particularly easy to manoeuvre the magnets over the tape; the magnets kept sticking to the tape
- Using **wax** (candle wax) was even more difficult.  I found that I need to heat the wax and press each magnet into warmed wax, which was tedious.  But again this did work.

After trying both theses methods I thought of another material that I could use:

- **Adhesive tack** (blu tack) turned out to be much easier to use as it could be squeezed around the magnets to collect the silt
  particles.

[image: tape with several blotches of silt, wax with patches of silt, blue tac uniformly darkened with silt, ring of clean spherical magnets, watch glass with larger particles in background]

---

I think the reason that I didn't think of any of theses options before asking this question was because I was overestimating the strength of the force that the magnet was exerting on the ferromagnetic particles, and underestimating the force of adhesives.

Unfortunately, I still haven't found a way to remove the ferromagnetic silt from the tape, wax, or tack.  But this isn't all that that important.  I am so glad that my magnets are now clean.